# How to create subcollection using Laravel 5 and mongodb

Tags: mongodb, laravel, collections, laravel-5, mongodb-query

First of all I'm new to laravel mongodb collection using jenssegers in laravel 5.0 . I would like to form a collection inside sub collection like below

```
    {
  "Uid": 1112,
  "AccountNo": 7620424,
  "Party": {
    "LanguageCode": "en",
    "Type": "individual",
    "Contact": [
      {
        "id" : It will be mongo object id How to create?
        "Type": "default",
        "Person": {
          "FullName": "Test Test"
        },
         {
        "id" : It will be mongo object id How to create?
        "Type": "default",
        "Person": {
          "FullName": "Test Test"
        },
        "MessagingMedium": [
          {
            "Id": It will be mongo object id How to create?
            "Scheme": "mailto",
            "URI": "demo1dd122@gmail.com",
            "Status": "awaiting.registration"
          },
          {
            "Id": It will be mongo object id How to create?
            "Scheme": "mailto",
            "URI": "demo1dd122@gmail.com",
            "Status": "awaiting.registration"
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  },
}
```

I have userprofile model

```
use Jenssegers\Mongodb\Model as Eloquent;

class UserProfile extends Eloquent  {

    protected $table = 'user_profile';
}

use Jenssegers\Mongodb\Model as Eloquent;

class Contact extends Eloquent  {

    protected $table = 'contact';
}
```

I have trying to create user profile after trying to add contacts subcollection to that created userprofile collection like below

```
$user = UserProfile::create(array('Uid' => $uId, 'AccountNo' => $accNo));
$card = Contact::create(['id' => 123]); //contact mongodb Eloquent
$card->userprofile()->save($card);
```

But its not working and the collection is not creating

Is that correct and i dont know abount hasmany, embedsmany colleciton

Anyone help me out

Answer (score 0):

You have to use the [embedsMany relation](https://github.com/jenssegers/laravel-mongodb#embedsmany-relations). This relation allows you to save arrays of objects (Eloquent objects with their own IDs) into existing documents. The relation will be completely managed by the ORM.

You can declare it like that :

```php
class UserProfile extends Eloquent
{
    // No table declaration because this model is only saved in the contact collection
}

class Contact extends Eloquent
{
    protected $table = 'contact';

    public function userProfiles()
    {
        return $this->embedsMany('UserProfile');
    }
}
```

If you want to embed only one object into an other, you can use the embedsOne relation.

And, before that, you should take a serious look at the package documentation ;)